# Jenkins - Email attachment with dynamic pdf files

Tags: jenkins

Using **Editable Email Notification** in Jenkins how do we get dynamic (report file name changing in workspace after every build) `.pdf` files attached in e-mail from workspace.

Example: `Root/TestResults/*.pdf`

Above will give all `pdf` attachments

Example: `Root/TestResults/Final_Report_2015_11_07_06_47.pdf`

Above path is giving same file when exist.

But file name is getting changed dynamically, i.e. `Final_Report_XXXX_XX_XX_XX_XX.pdf`.

Is there any way to get latest file based one dynamic report file name check.

Comment: How is/are the `pdf`file/s built? How is/are the file name/s created?